# Can ReactJS websites be split into multiple separate apps?

Tags: reactjs, modularity, separation-of-concerns

I have recently started playing around with ReactJS framework. One thing I have noticed though is that the apps can quickly become clustered. Now, I come from the OOP background where you can completely separate apps into different projects that work based on instantiation / calls.

I was wondering if it was possible in react? i.e. instead of creating a huge application with login, dashboard and 5 different services, have one dashboard that points to each of the services as a standalone application? Also, what would be the best practice for approaching such thing?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried it and came across some issues?

Comment: Check for [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)